# Use Hilbert style proofs to solve problem

Tags: logic

Solve this problem by using Hilbert style proof:

$ A,B \vdash A \equiv B $

my try :

- (1) A (hyp)
- (2) B (hyp)
- (3) $ A \land B $ (merge)
- (4) $ A \land B \equiv A \equiv B \equiv A \lor B $ (golden rule)
- (5) $ A \equiv B \equiv A \lor B $ (3,4 + equ)
- (6) $ A \lor B \equiv A \equiv B $ (Symmetry)

That was my try. I don't know if it was right. I couldn't continue.

Inference rules : leibniz and equanimity.

Lists of axioms and theorems :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the axioms and/or rules of inference of your system?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Please see my edit for the axioms and rules of inference.

Answer (score 1):

We will start from George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008), **Example 2.5.1(1)**, page 77 :

*(1)* $\quad A, B \vdash A \land B$

and use the *Golden Rule*, page 43 :

> $$(A \land B) \equiv (A \equiv (B \equiv A \lor B))$$

Applying *Equanimity* [page 40], from *(1)* we have :

*(2)* $\quad A,B \vdash (A \equiv (B \equiv A \lor B))$

From the axiom about **Associativity of** $\equiv$ : $(A \equiv (B \equiv C)) \equiv (A \equiv B) \equiv C)$, by *Equanimity* :

*(3)* $\quad A,B \vdash (A \equiv B) \equiv (A \lor B)$

Using again **Example 2.5.1(3)** :

*(4)* $\quad A \vdash A \lor B$

we apply again *Equanimity* :

> *(5)* $\quad A,B \vdash (A \equiv B)$.